# Calculating the sum of square residuals?

Tags: matlab, regression

I'm attempting to write a code for regression of nutritional rating vs sugar and fiber. And Calculating the sum of square residuals, R2, and standard error of estimation, s.

I'm new to matlab but have been following the methods in https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html

```
  z=csvread('Cereals no alpha.csv');
    [rows,cols]=size(z);
    disp([rows,cols])
    sugar=z(:,7);
    fiber=z(:,5);
    rating=z(:,13);

    %Regression
    V=ones(rows,3);
    V(:,2)=sugar;
    V(:,3)=fiber;
    A=V'*V;
    b=V'*rating;
    w =A\b;

    b0=w(1);
    bs=w(2);
    bf=w(3);
    disp([b0,bs,bf])

    %Sum squared error performance function
    %perf = sse(z,sugar,fiber);
    %disp(perf)


    %R^2 maybe?
    %Use polyfit to compute a linear regression that predicts y from x:
    p = polyfit(sugar,fiber,1)

    %fit equation
    yfit =p(1)*sugar+p(2);

    %Compute the residual values as a vector of signed numbers:
    yresid = fiber-yfit;

    %Square the residuals and total them to obtain the residual sum of 
    SSresid =sum(yresid.^2);

    %Compute the total sum of squares of y by multiplying the variance of
    by the number of observations minus 1:
    SStotal = (length(fiber)-1) * var(fiber);

    %Compute R2
    rsq = 1 - SSresid/SStotal
```

Gives:
disp([b0,bs,bf]) = 51.7635   -2.2012    2.8661

p = -0.0761    2.6797

rsq = 0.0199

But from the data I was expecting roughly a R2 = 80.8% and s = 6.24 for regression

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: `A=V'*V; b=V'*rating; w =A\b;` <-- WHY ?  why are you not simply using `w = V\rating` ? For the second part your method is correct, the result simply indicate that there is almost no linear correlation between your two variables.

Comment: You can calculate the least squares solution with the matrix approach as @obchardon mentions or you could take advantage of the fact that least squares is convex & use [`fminsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html).  `[CoefsFit, SSE] = fminsearch(@(Coefs) (Y - (Coefs*X.')).^2, Coefs0)` where `X` is a *n by p* matrix (data), and your `Coefs` is a `1 by p` vector.